# How to prove that the the following limit exist and is equal to 0

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Given $E_i=\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$, $i=1,\ldots, k$, how to prove that for $h=(h_1,\ldots, h_k)$, each $h_i\in E_i$, the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{|h_1|\cdots |h_k|}{|h|}=0?$$(Here $|\cdot |$ denote the usual norm)

In the case $k=2$ this is true but the argument used in the proof is not adaptable for the general case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you write $h \to 0$, do you mean that each component of $h$, and thus each component of every $h_i$, go to zero? If so, I might look at the max of all components and see what I can get from that max $\to 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each quocient $|h_i|/|h|$ is upper bounded. The product of the others $h_j$ when $h\to 0$ goes to $0$. Therefore the limit is zero.